# Why forEach and map behave differently in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first cut

```
export default class Form extends Component {

  renderResult(result) {
    return (
      <span key={result.id}>{result.id}</span>
    )
  }


  render() {
    const { entity, results } = this.props.response;

    return (
      <div key="result" className="row">
        {results.map(
          (result) => this.renderResult(result)
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It works as I expected. In my output I can see a number of `<span/>` get generated.

Since I need to display result differently based on the `result`'s order inside the array, I want to pass an index variable into the render function. I tried to switch to  `forEach`

```
export default class Form extends Component {

  renderResult(idx, result) {
    // if idx then do this else ...
    return (
      <span key={result.id}>{result.id}</span>
    )
  }


  render() {
    const { entity, results } = this.props.response;

    return (
      <div key="result" className="row">
        {results.forEach(
          (response, idx) => this.renderResult(idx, response)
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In this version, however, it fails to output any `span` element.

Why is the difference?

Comment: `forEach` returns nothing, I'm not sure what you're expecting. `map` callbacks get an index too, why are you trying to use `forEach`?

Comment: I don't know map get an index too. Besides I expect `forEach` and `map` to be interchangeable. Not a reasonable expectation?

Comment: `forEach` just does that, it calls a callback for each item. `map` collects the return values from each callback, and returns an array, `forEach` returns nothing.

Comment: I see. If you made your comment an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach` has a return type of `undefined`. The values returned by the callbacks are simply discarded.

`.map` has a return type of `Array`. The values returned by the callbacks are collected into an array.

You seem to be attempting to use `.forEach` if it were map under the incorrect assumption that `.forEach` takes an index as an argument but `.map` does not, which is incorrect. Both take callbacks of the form `function(item, index, items){`.